# Reading Latitude and longitude from CSV file and display in google map after applying filtering to a column

Tags: android, csv, google-maps, arraylist

I managed to fetch long and lat values from CSV and loop them to display all values in google map .Now i need to filter column Fuel_Type = "Unleaded 91" how to add this to while loop ?
*while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null)*

here is my code to fetch data from CSV

```
 private void readDataFromCSV() {
        // Read the raw csv file
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
        );
        boolean header = true;
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        List<LatLng> latLngList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        // Initialization
        try {
            reader.readLine();
            while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) // Read until end of file
            {
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(line.split(",")[7]);
                double lon = Double.parseDouble(line.split(",")[8]);
                latLngList.add(new LatLng(lat, lon));
            }

// Add them to map
            for(LatLng pos : latLngList)
            {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pos).title("title").icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.seveneleven)));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(pos, 18f));
                mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(MapsActivity.this));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.wtf("MapsActivity", "Error reading data file on line" + line, e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**my CSV file :**

```
SiteId,Site_Name,Site_Brand,Sites_Address_Line_1,Site_Suburb,Site_State,Site_Post_Code,Site_Latitude,Site_Longitude,Fuel_Type,Price,TransactionDateutc
61291313,7-Eleven Runaway Bay,BP,20 Bayview Street,Mungindi,QLD,4497,-27.923529,153.403729,Unleaded 91,1840,1/3/2022 0:00
61291313,Caltex Labrador,BP,150 Brisbane Road,Mungindi,QLD,4497,-27.924007,153.403869,Diesel,1860,2/3/2022 21:49
61291313,Coles shell,BP,69 Frank Street,Mungindi,QLD,4497,-27.923863,153.403528,Diesel,1900,3/3/2022 22:21
61291313,BP Shop Helensvale,BP,2 Discovery Drive,Mungindi,QLD,4497,-27.923655,153.403608,Diesel,2150,9/3/2022 23:12
```

Comment: Tried to below code but result were always true but i need to display values not true or false  List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();  String fuel_type = new String(line.split(",")[9]);
                list.add(String.valueOf(fuel_type.contains("Unleaded 91")));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check if `line` contains your fuel type or not, like this:

```
while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) // Read until end of file
   {
       if(line.contains("YOUR_FUEL_TYPE"){
           double lat = Double.parseDouble(line.split(",")[7]);
           double lon = Double.parseDouble(line.split(",")[8]);
           latLngList.add(new LatLng(lat, long));

       }
}
```

Comment: HI @Mahdi , Thanks a Lot .Thats really helped.